# How to optimize a GROUP BY query

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I am given a task to optimize the following query (not written by me)

```sql
SELECT
  "u"."email" as email,
  r.url as "domain",
  "u"."id" as "requesterId",
  s.total * 100 / count("r"."id") as "rate",
  count(("r"."url", "u"."email", "u"."id", s."total")) OVER () as total
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      url,
      id,
      "requesterId",
      created_at
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          url,
          id,
          "requesterId",
          created_at,
          row_number() over (partition by main_request_uuid) as row_number
        FROM
          "requests" "request"
        GROUP BY
          main_request_uuid,
          retry_number,
          url,
          id,
          "requesterId",
          created_at
        ORDER BY
          main_request_uuid ASC,
          retry_number DESC
      ) "request_"
    WHERE
      request_.row_number = 1
  ) "r"
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      "requesterId",
      url,
      count(created_at) AS "total"
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          url,
          status,
          created_at,
          "requesterId"
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
              url,
              status,
              created_at,
              "requesterId",
              row_number() over (partition by main_request_uuid) as row_number
            FROM
              "requests" "request"
            GROUP BY
              main_request_uuid,
              retry_number,
              url,
              status,
              created_at,
              "requesterId"
            ORDER BY
              main_request_uuid ASC,
              retry_number DESC
          ) "request_"
        WHERE
          request_.row_number = 1
      ) "s"
    WHERE
      status IN ('success')
      AND s."created_at" :: date >= '2022-01-07' :: date
      AND s."created_at" :: date <= '2022-02-07' :: date
    GROUP BY
      s.url,
      s."requesterId"
  ) "s" ON s."requesterId" = r."requesterId"
  AND s.url = r.url
  INNER JOIN "users" "u" ON "u"."id" = r."requesterId"
WHERE
  r."created_at" :: date >= '2022-01-07' :: date
  AND r."created_at" :: date <= '2022-02-07' :: date
GROUP BY
  r.url,
  "u"."email",
  "u"."id",
  s.total
LIMIT
  10
```

So there is the `requests` table, which stores some API requests and there is a mechanism to retry a request if it fails, which is repeated 5 times, while keeping separate rows for each retry. If after 5 times it still fails, it's not continued anymore. This is the reason for the `partition by` subquery, which selects only the main requests.

What the query should return is the total number of requests and success rate, grouped by the `url` and `requesterId`. The query I was given is not only wrong, but also takes huge amounts of time to execute, so I came up with the optimized version below

```sql
WITH a AS (SELECT url,
                  id,
                  status,
                  "requesterId",
                  created_at
           FROM (
                    SELECT url,
                           id,
                           status,
                           "requesterId",
                           created_at,
                           row_number() over (partition by main_request_uuid) as row_number
                    FROM "requests" "request"
                    WHERE
                    created_at:: date >= '2022-01-07' :: date
                    AND created_at :: date <= '2022-02-07' :: date
                    GROUP BY main_request_uuid,
                             retry_number,
                             url,
                             id,
                             status,
                             "requesterId",
                             created_at
                    ORDER BY
                             main_request_uuid ASC,
                             retry_number DESC
                ) "request_"
           WHERE request_.row_number = 1),
     b AS (SELECT count(*) total, a2.url as url, a2."requesterId" FROM a a2 GROUP BY a2.url, a2."requesterId"),
     c AS (SELECT count(*) success, a3.url as url, a3."requesterId"
           FROM a a3
           WHERE status IN ('success')
           GROUP BY a3.url, a3."requesterId")
SELECT success * 100 / total as rate, b.url, b."requesterId", total, email
FROM b
         JOIN c ON b.url = c.url AND b."requesterId" = c."requesterId" JOIN users u ON b."requesterId" = u.id
LIMIT 10;
```

What the new version basically does is select all the main requests, and count the successful ones and the total count. The new version still takes a lot of time to execute (around 60s on a table with 4 million requests).

Is there a way to optimize this further?

You can see the table structure below. The table has no relevant indexes, but adding one on `(url, requesterId)` had no effect

| column_name | data_type |
| --- | --- |
| id | bigint |
| requesterId | bigint |
| proxyId | bigint |
| url | character varying |
| status | USER-DEFINED |
| time_spent | integer |
| created_at | timestamp with time zone |
| request_information | jsonb |
| retry_number | smallint |
| main_request_uuid | character varying |

And here is the execution plan on a backup table with 100k rows. It's taking 1.1s for 100k rows, but it would be more desired to at least cut it down to 200ms for this case

```
Limit  (cost=15196.40..15204.56 rows=1 width=77) (actual time=749.664..1095.476 rows=10 loops=1)
  CTE a
    ->  Subquery Scan on request_  (cost=15107.66..15195.96 rows=3 width=159) (actual time=226.805..591.188 rows=49474 loops=1)
          Filter: (request_.row_number = 1)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 70962
          ->  WindowAgg  (cost=15107.66..15188.44 rows=602 width=206) (actual time=226.802..571.185 rows=120436 loops=1)
                ->  Group  (cost=15107.66..15179.41 rows=602 width=198) (actual time=226.797..435.340 rows=120436 loops=1)
"                      Group Key: request.main_request_uuid, request.retry_number, request.url, request.id, request.status, request.""requesterId"", request.created_at"
                      ->  Gather Merge  (cost=15107.66..15170.62 rows=502 width=198) (actual time=226.795..386.198 rows=120436 loops=1)
                            Workers Planned: 2
                            Workers Launched: 2
                            ->  Group  (cost=14107.64..14112.66 rows=251 width=198) (actual time=212.749..269.504 rows=40145 loops=3)
"                                  Group Key: request.main_request_uuid, request.retry_number, request.url, request.id, request.status, request.""requesterId"", request.created_at"
                                  ->  Sort  (cost=14107.64..14108.27 rows=251 width=198) (actual time=212.744..250.031 rows=40145 loops=3)
"                                        Sort Key: request.main_request_uuid, request.retry_number DESC, request.url, request.id, request.status, request.""requesterId"", request.created_at"
                                        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 7952kB
                                        Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8568kB
                                        Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 9072kB
                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on requests request  (cost=0.00..14097.63 rows=251 width=198) (actual time=0.024..44.013 rows=40145 loops=3)
                                              Filter: (((created_at)::date >= '2022-01-07'::date) AND ((created_at)::date <= '2022-02-07'::date))
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..8.59 rows=1 width=77) (actual time=749.662..1095.364 rows=10 loops=1)
"        Join Filter: (a2.""requesterId"" = u.id)"
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.16..0.28 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=749.630..1095.163 rows=10 loops=1)
"              Join Filter: (((a2.url)::text = (a3.url)::text) AND (a2.""requesterId"" = a3.""requesterId""))"
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 69
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.08..0.09 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=703.128..703.139 rows=10 loops=1)
"                    Group Key: a3.url, a3.""requesterId"""
                    Batches: 5  Memory Usage: 4297kB  Disk Usage: 7040kB
                    ->  CTE Scan on a a3  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=226.808..648.251 rows=41278 loops=1)
                          Filter: (status = 'success'::requests_status_enum)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 8196
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.08..0.11 rows=3 width=48) (actual time=38.103..38.105 rows=8 loops=10)
"                    Group Key: a2.url, a2.""requesterId"""
                    Batches: 41  Memory Usage: 4297kB  Disk Usage: 7328kB
                    ->  CTE Scan on a a2  (cost=0.00..0.06 rows=3 width=40) (actual time=0.005..7.419 rows=49474 loops=10)
"        ->  Index Scan using ""PK_a3ffb1c0c8416b9fc6f907b7433"" on users u  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=10)"
"              Index Cond: (id = a3.""requesterId"")"
Planning Time: 1.494 ms
Execution Time: 1102.488 ms
```

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: @O.Jones thank you for the tip, I added some more information

Comment: Why is the LIMIT there?  Your description of the problem does not imply the presence of a LIMIT.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning.

Comment: You should test on more realistic data sizes.  Optimal plans can depend on total sizes.  Also your work_mem is too low even for this size of data and will be way too low for a larger size.

Comment: In your query no need to add group by and order by when partition by used here. and rearrange query... but you don't provide sample data with table structure and also output.

Answer (score 2):

These lines of your plan point to a possible optimization.

```
->  Parallel Seq Scan on requests request  (cost=0.00..14097.63 rows=251 width=198) (actual time=0.024..44.013 rows=40145 loops=3)
    Filter: (((created_at)::date >= '2022-01-07'::date) AND ((created_at)::date <= '2022-02-07'::date))
```

Sequential scans, parallel or not, are somewhat costly.

So, try changing these WHERE conditions to make them [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) and useful for a range scan.

```sql
    created_at:: date >= '2022-01-07' :: date 
AND created_at :: date <= '2022-02-07' :: date
```

Change these to

```sql
    created_at >= '2022-01-07' :: date
AND created_at < '2022-01-07' :: date + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

And, put a BTREE index on the `created_at` column.

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON requests (created_at);
```

Your query is complex, so I'm not totally sure this will work. But try it. The index should pull out only the rows for the dates you need.

And, your `LIMIT` clause without an accompanying `ORDER BY` clause gives postgreSQL permission to give you back whatever ten rows it wants from the result set. Don't use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`. Don't do it at all unless you need it.

Comment: Unfortunately creating the index or the sargable condition had no effect. And I don't know what it is supposed to be ordered by (whoever gave me the task doesn't know either), so I cannot put anything there, but it must return only 10 items, so I didn't change anything there

Answer (score 1):

Writing query efficiently is one of the major part for query optimization specially for handling huge data set. Always avoiding unnecessary GROUP BY or ORDER BY or explicit type casting or too many joins or extra subquery or limit/limit without order by (if possible) if handling large volume of data and meet desired requirement. Create an index in created_at column. If LEFT JOIN used in your given query then query pattern would be changed. My observations are

```
-- avoid unnecessary GROUP BY (no aggregate function use) or ORDER BY 
SELECT url
         , id
         , status
         , "requesterId"
         , created_at
    FROM (SELECT url
               , id
               , status
               , "requesterId"
               , created_at
               , row_number() over (partition by main_request_uuid order by retry_number DESC) as row_number
         FROM "requests" "request"
         WHERE (created_at:: date >= '2022-01-07'
             AND created_at :: date <= '2022-02-07')) "request_"
         WHERE request_.row_number = 1
```

**N.B.:** if created_at column data type is timestamp without time zone then no need to extra casting. Follow the below statement

```
(created_at >= '2022-01-07'
                 AND created_at <= '2022-02-07') 

-- Combine two CTE into one as per requirement
SELECT url, "requesterId", COUNT(1) total
         , COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE status = 'success') success 
        FROM a
        -- WHERE status IN ('success')
        GROUP BY url, "requesterId"
```

So the final query as like below

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT url
         , id
         , status
         , "requesterId"
         , created_at
    FROM (SELECT url
               , id
               , status
               , "requesterId"
               , created_at
               , row_number() over (partition by main_request_uuid order by retry_number DESC) as row_number
         FROM "requests" "request"
         WHERE (created_at:: date >= '2022-01-07'
             AND created_at :: date <= '2022-02-07')) "request_"
         WHERE request_.row_number = 1    
), b as (
    SELECT url, "requesterId", COUNT(1) total
         , COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE status = 'success') success 
        FROM a
        -- WHERE status IN ('success')
        GROUP BY url, "requesterId"
) select (success * 100) / total as rate
       , b.url, b."requesterId", total, email
from b
JOIN users u 
  ON u.id = b."requesterId"
limit 10;
```

If above query doesn't meet requirement then try below query. But this query will perfect if using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT url
         , id
         , status
         , "requesterId"
         , created_at
    FROM (SELECT url
               , id
               , status
               , "requesterId"
               , created_at
               , row_number() over (partition by main_request_uuid order by retry_number DESC) as row_number
         FROM "requests" "request"
         WHERE (created_at:: date >= '2022-01-07'
             AND created_at :: date <= '2022-02-07')) "request_"
         WHERE request_.row_number = 1    
), b as (
    SELECT count(1) total, a2.url as url, a2."requesterId" 
    FROM a a2 
    GROUP BY a2.url, a2."requesterId"
), c AS (SELECT count(1) success, a3.url as url, a3."requesterId"
         FROM a a3
         WHERE status = 'success'
         GROUP BY a3.url, a3."requesterId")
SELECT success * 100 / total as rate, b.url, b."requesterId", total, email
FROM b
JOIN c 
  ON b.url = c.url AND b."requesterId" = c."requesterId" 
JOIN users u 
  ON b."requesterId" = u.id
LIMIT 10;

 select (success * 100) / total as rate
       , b.url, b."requesterId", total, email
from b
JOIN users u 
  ON u.id = b."requesterId"
limit 10;
```

Comment: Still the same performance. But the idea of combining two CTEs into one is helpful, so I think what I'll do is get rid of the partitioning, and instead add a new column to the table, like `isMainRequest`, to avoid querying and grouping unnecessary rows

Comment: Please increase the size of work_mem and maintenance_work_mem in configuration file. As group by and order by clause are used in query and return large number of rows so configuration can make few issues. Better idea for adding a new column in table. Also create range partition. Thanks for response @EM-D

Comment: The `work_mem` is set to 4MB and `maintenance_work_mem` is 64MB. should those be higher? I don't really have control on it (same with range partitioning) on the production DB, but if increasing them will help I'll try to do something. Thank you as well

Comment: Yes it's default value at the time of installation. But it needs to increase as per current need. Also execute VACUUM FULL at downtime for every 7 days of your entire DB or a specific table. It's remove the dead tuple and rebuild indexes.